# Upgrade App Engine app to Python 3: How to provision Flask to run multiple, distinct apps

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine

I'm trying to upgrade my App Engine app from Python 2 to Python 3, replacing webapp2 with Flask. What is the best way to provision routing for my existing app structure which resembles the following:

```
/ - routes to main.py
/myapp1 - routes to myapp1.py
/myapp2 - routes to myapp2.py
```

main.py, myapp1.py, myapp2.py live in the same directory

The ability to use "handlers:" within app.yaml appears to no longer be available with Flask(?). I've been tinkering with Blueprints and Application Dispatching but that appears to expect that everything run through main.py (a "driver" module if you will).

I'm new to Flask so perhaps I'm missing something simple. I'd prefer not to restructure my application into subdirectories at this stage, as there's plenty of other changes to deal with for this upgrade.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. GAE Standard for Python 3 uses an `entrypoint` in your `app.yaml` file. If you don't specify one, `dev_appserver.py` will use a default of `gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app` (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup)).
2. From the above, it means you'll have to '*tell main.py to route to different files if certain conditions (url paths) are met*'. This is achieved via `Blueprint`

   **myapp1.py**

   ```
   from flask import Blueprint
   myapp1_handlers = Blueprint('myapp1_handlers', __name__, 
   template_folder='templates')


   @myapp1_handlers.route("/myapp1/") 
   def home():
       return "myapp1 - This is home page"

   @admin_handlers.route("/admin/1/") 
   def home_1():
       return "myapp1 - This is page 1"
   ```

   **main.py**

   ```
   from flask import Flask

   # Import the handlers defined in the Blueprint for myapp1_handlers
   from myapp1 import myapp1_handlers 

   app = Flask(__name__)

   # Register your blueprint so that any route matching 
   # what you've defined in the blueprint will get routed to it
   app.register_blueprint(myapp1_handlers)


   @app.route("/") 
   def home():
       return "Main App - This is home page"


   @app.route("/1/") 
   def home_1():
       return "Main App - This is page 1"
   ```

   a. Start your app by running `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`. It will display *'Main App - This is home page'*

   b. Change the url to `/myapp1` and it should now display *'myapp1 - This is home page'*

**Another Solution:**

Instead of using Blueprint, another option is to make each of myapp1, myapp2 a [service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) (we have a blog article with an example and explanation [here](https://nocommandline.com/blog/managing-large-apps-on-google-app-engine/)).

Each of them will need to have its own 'app.yaml' e.g. myapp1.yaml, myapp2.yaml. You'll then create a `dispatch.yaml` file which says route anything with a path of `myapp1` to myapp1 service and anything with a path of `myapp2` to myapp2 service and everything else to your default service. This means you'll end up with something like this

**dispatch.yaml**

```
dispatch:


# Send all traffic for paths that include /myapp1/ to the myapp1 service
- url: "*/myapp1/*"
  service: myapp1
  

# Send all other traffic to the default service. 
- url: "*/*"
  service: default
```

**myapp1.yaml**

```
service: myapp1
runtime: python39

# Tell GAE to check myapp1.py for the 'app' object
# This means you need to have it in myapp.py too
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT myapp1:app
```

Notice that there's an entrypoint in `myapp1.yaml`. If you don't include it, GAE will assume the default entrypoint (as earlier stated) and will go look for your `main.py` file.

I have not included code for your default service i.e. your `app.yaml` file